# Spring Scheduling Как извлечь обьект?

Tags: java, spring

Есть класс, который по шедулеру наполняет коллекцию определенными обьектами

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

    public static List<SomeObject> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 300000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() throws IOException {

      arraylist.add(что-то);

    }
}
```

Возможно ли как-то получить данные arraylist из другого класса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто добавьте к компоненту геттер:

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {
    ...

    public List<SomeObject> getArraylist() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(arraylist);
    }
}

@Service
public class SomeService {
    @Autowired
    ScheduledTasks scheduledTasks;

    public void someMethod() {
        List<SomeObject> list = scheduledTasks.getArraylist();
        ...
    }
}
```